# ARM disassembler from ELF file in C

Tags: optimization, c

I'm writing a simple disassembler in C for learning. It is supposed to take a ELF file read in the contents of the ELF header then the individual program headers (potentially multiple) and print out various information on the file and then print each ARM code out.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "elf.h"

void Disassemble(unsigned int *armI, int count, unsigned int startAddress);
void DecodeInstruction(unsigned int instr, unsigned int Address);
void HexToBinary(int *bits, unsigned int hex);
int SignExtend(unsigned int x, int bits);
int Rotate(unsigned int rotatee, int amount);
void PrintASCII(unsigned int instr);
void ProcessSWI(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr);
void ProcessBranch(int *bits, unsigned int instr, unsigned int currentAddress, char *instructionPtr);
void ProcessDP(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr);
void ProcessLDR(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr);
void ProcessMUL (int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr);
void ProcessLDM(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  FILE *fp;
  ELFHEADER elfhead;
  int i;
  unsigned int *armInstructions = NULL;

  if(argc < 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: DisARM <filename>\n");
      return 1;
    }

/* Open ELF file for binary reading */
  if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
/* Read in the header */
  fread(&elfhead, 1, sizeof(ELFHEADER), fp);
  if(!(elfhead.magic[0] == 0177 && elfhead.magic[1] == 'E' && elfhead.magic[2] == 'L' && elfhead.magic[3] == 'F'))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an ELF file\n", argv[1]);
      return 2;
    }
  printf("\nFile-type: %d\n",elfhead.filetype);
  printf("Arch-type: %d\n",elfhead.archtype);
  printf("Entry: %x\n", elfhead.entry);
  printf("Prog-Header: %x\n", elfhead.phdrpos);
  printf("Prog-Header-count: %d\n", elfhead.phdrcnt);
  printf("Section-Header: %x\n", elfhead.shdrpos);

/* Find and read program headers */
  ELFPROGHDR *prgHdr;

  fseek(fp, elfhead.phdrpos, SEEK_SET);
  prgHdr = (ELFPROGHDR *)malloc(elfhead.phdrcnt * sizeof(ELFPROGHDR));
  if(!prgHdr)
    {
      fprintf(fp, "Out of Memory\n");
      fclose(fp);
      return 3;
    }

  fread(prgHdr, 1, sizeof(ELFPROGHDR)*elfhead.phdrcnt, fp);

/* allocate memory and read in ARM instructions */

  for(i = 0; i < elfhead.phdrcnt; i++)
    {
      printf("Segment-Offset: %x\n", prgHdr[i].offset);
      printf("File-size: %d\n", prgHdr[i].filesize);
      printf("Align: %d\n", prgHdr[i].align);
      armInstructions = (unsigned int *)malloc(prgHdr[i].filesize + 3 & ~3);
      if(armInstructions == NULL)
    {
      fclose(fp);
      free(prgHdr);
      fprintf(stderr, "Out of Memory\n");
      return 3;
    }
      fseek(fp, prgHdr[i].offset, SEEK_SET);
      fread(armInstructions, 1, prgHdr[i].filesize, fp);

/* Disassemble */
      printf("\nInstructions\n\n");

      Disassemble(armInstructions, (prgHdr[i].filesize + 3 & ~3) /4, prgHdr[i].virtaddr);
      printf("\n"); 
      free(armInstructions);
    }
  free(prgHdr);
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}

void Disassemble(unsigned int *armI, int count, unsigned int startAddress)
{
  int i;
  printf("Address   Hex       ASCII\tDisassembly\n");
  printf("=============================================\n");
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      printf("%08X  %08X", startAddress + i*4, armI[i]);
      DecodeInstruction(armI[i], startAddress + i*4);
      printf("\n");
    }

}

void DecodeInstruction(unsigned int instr, unsigned int Address)
{
  int bits[32];
  char instruction[100];

  sprintf(instruction, "\0");

  HexToBinary(bits, instr);
  printf("  ");
  PrintASCII(instr);
  printf("\t");

  if (instr == 0)
    strcat(instruction, "NOP");
  else if (bits[27] && bits[26] && bits[25] && bits[24])
    ProcessSWI(bits, instr, instruction);
  else if (bits[27] && !bits[26] && bits[25])
    ProcessBranch(bits, instr, Address, instruction);
  else if (!bits[27] && bits[26])
    {
      if (!bits[25]) 
    ProcessLDR(bits, instr, instruction);
      else if (bits[4])
    strcat(instruction, "Undefined Instruction.");
      else if (!bits[4])
    ProcessLDR(bits, instr, instruction);
    }
  else if (bits[27] && !bits[26] && !bits[25])
    ProcessLDM(bits, instr, instruction);
  else if (!(bits[27] || bits[26] || bits[25] || bits[24] || bits[23] || bits[22]) && (bits[7] && !bits[6] && !bits[5] && bits[4]))
    ProcessMUL(bits, instr, instruction);
  else if (!bits[27] && !bits[26])
    ProcessDP(bits, instr, instruction);
  else
    strcat(instruction, "Undefined Instruction.");

  printf("%s", instruction);

/* DEBUG PRINT BINARY */
  /*printf("\t\t");
    for(int i=31;i>=0;i--)
    {
    printf("%d", bits[i]);
    }*/
}

int SignExtend(unsigned int x, int bits)
{
  int r;
  int m = 1U << (bits - 1);
  x = x & ((1U << bits) - 1); 
  r = (x ^ m) - m;
  return r;
}

int Rotate(unsigned int rotatee, int amount)
{
  unsigned int mask, lo, hi;

  mask = (1 << amount) - 1;
  lo = rotatee & mask;
  hi = rotatee >> amount;

  rotatee = (lo << (32 - amount)) | hi;

  return rotatee;
}

void HexToBinary(int *bits, unsigned int hex)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
    {
      bits[i] = (hex >> i) & 1;
    }
}

void PrintCCode(unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr)
{
  switch((instr & 0xF0000000) >> 28)
    {
    case(13): strcat(instructionPtr, "LE"); break;
    case(12): strcat(instructionPtr, "GT"); break;
    case(11): strcat(instructionPtr, "LT"); break;
    case(10): strcat(instructionPtr, "GE"); break;
    case(9): strcat(instructionPtr, "LS"); break;
    case(8): strcat(instructionPtr, "HI"); break;
    case(7): strcat(instructionPtr, "VC"); break;
    case(6): strcat(instructionPtr, "VS"); break;
    case(5): strcat(instructionPtr, "PL"); break;
    case(4): strcat(instructionPtr, "MI"); break;
    case(3): strcat(instructionPtr, "CC/LO"); break;
    case(2): strcat(instructionPtr, "CS/HS"); break;
    case(1): strcat(instructionPtr, "NE"); break;
    case(0): strcat(instructionPtr, "EQ"); break;
    }
}

void PrintASCII(unsigned int instr)
{
  char c[5];
  int i;

  c[0] = (instr & 0x000000FF);
  c[1] = (instr & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
  c[2] = (instr & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
  c[3] = (instr & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      if(isalpha(c[i]) || ispunct(c[i]))
    printf("%c", c[i]);
      else
    printf("*");
    }
}

void ProcessSWI(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr)
{
  strcat(instructionPtr, "SWI");
  PrintCCode(instr, instructionPtr);
  sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "\t%X", instr & 0x00FFFFFF);
}

void ProcessBranch(int *bits, unsigned int instr, unsigned int currentAddress, char *instructionPtr)
{
  if ( bits[24] )
    strcat(instructionPtr, "BL");
  else
    strcat(instructionPtr, "B");
  PrintCCode(instr, instructionPtr);
  sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "\t&%X", (SignExtend((instr & 0x00FFFFFF) << 2, 26)) + currentAddress + 8);
}

void ProcessDP(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr)
{
  int DP = (instr & 0x01E00000) >> 21;
  int Rd = (instr & 0x0000F000) >> 12;
  int Rn = (instr & 0x000F0000) >> 16;
  int Rot = (instr & 0x00000F00) >> 8;
  int Op = (instr & 0x000000FF);
  int Rm = (instr & 0x0000000F);
  int Sh = (instr & 0x00000060) >> 5;
  int Shift;

  switch(DP)
    {
    case(15): strcat(instructionPtr, "MVN"); break;
    case(14): strcat(instructionPtr, "BIC"); break;
    case(13): strcat(instructionPtr, "MOV"); break;
    case(12): strcat(instructionPtr, "ORR"); break;
    case(11): strcat(instructionPtr, "CMN"); break;
    case(10): strcat(instructionPtr, "CMP"); break;
    case(9): strcat(instructionPtr, "TEQ"); break;
    case(8): strcat(instructionPtr, "TST"); break;
    case(7): strcat(instructionPtr, "RSC"); break;
    case(6): strcat(instructionPtr, "SBC"); break;
    case(5): strcat(instructionPtr, "ADC"); break;
    case(4): strcat(instructionPtr, "ADD"); break;
    case(3): strcat(instructionPtr, "RSB"); break;
    case(2): strcat(instructionPtr, "SUB"); break;
    case(1): strcat(instructionPtr, "EOR"); break;
    case(0): strcat(instructionPtr, "AND"); break;
    }

  PrintCCode(instr, instructionPtr);
  if (bits[20] && DP != 10 && DP != 11)
    strcat(instructionPtr, "S");

  if (DP != 11 && DP != 10)
    sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "\tR%d, ", Rd);
  else
    strcat(instructionPtr, "\t");

  if (DP != 13 && DP != 15)
    sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "R%d, ", Rn);

  if (bits[25])
    {
      if (!(bits[11] || bits[10] || bits[9] || bits[8]))
    sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "#&%X", Op);
      else
    sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "#&%X", Rotate(Op, Rot*2));
    }
  else
    {
      if (bits[4])
    Shift = (instr & 0x00000F00) >> 8;
      else
    Shift = (instr & 0x00000F80) >> 7;
      sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "R%d", Rm);
      if (Shift > 0)
    {
      switch(Sh)
        {
        case(3): if(Shift == 0) strcat(instructionPtr, ", RRX"); else strcat(instructionPtr, ", ROR "); break;
        case(2): strcat(instructionPtr, ", ASR "); break;
        case(1): strcat(instructionPtr, ", LSR "); break;
        case(0): strcat(instructionPtr, ", LSL "); break;
        }
      sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "#&%X", Shift);
    }
    }
}

void ProcessLDR(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr)
{
  int sourceReg = (instr & 0x0000F000) >> 12;
  int baseReg = (instr & 0x000F0000) >> 16;
  int Rm = (instr & 0x0000000F);
  int immediate = (instr & 0x00000FFF);
  int Shift = (instr & 0x00000F80) >> 7;
  int Sh = (instr & 0x00000060) >> 5;

    if (bits[20])
      strcat(instructionPtr, "LDR");
    else
      strcat(instructionPtr, "STR");

    PrintCCode(instr, instructionPtr);
    if (bits[22])
      strcat(instructionPtr, "B");

    sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "\tR%d", sourceReg);

    if (bits[24]) // Pre incremented
      {
        sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", [R%d", baseReg);
    if (bits[25])
      sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", R%d]", Rm);
    else
      {
        if (immediate > 0)
          sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", #%d]", immediate);
        else
          strcat(instructionPtr, "]");
      }
    if (bits[21])
      strcat(instructionPtr, "!");
      }
    else // Post incremented
      {
    if (bits[21])
      strcat(instructionPtr, "!");
        sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", [R%d]", baseReg);
    if (bits[25])
      {
        if(bits[23])
          sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", R%d", Rm);
        else
          sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", -R%x", Rm); 

        if (Shift > 0)
          {
        switch(Sh)
          {
          case(3): if(Shift == 0) strcat(instructionPtr, ", RRX"); else strcat(instructionPtr, ", ROR "); break;
          case(2): strcat(instructionPtr, ", ASR "); break;
          case(1): strcat(instructionPtr, ", LSR "); break;
          case(0): strcat(instructionPtr, ", LSL "); break;
          }
            sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "#&%X", Shift*2); //DOUBLED..
          }
      }
    else
      {
        if (bits[23])
          sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", #&%x", immediate);
        else
          sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), ", #-&%x", immediate); 
      }
      }
}

void ProcessMUL (int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr)
{
  int Rd = (instr & 0x000F0000) >> 16;
  int Rm = instr & 0x0000000F;
  int Rs = (instr & 0x00000F00) >> 8;
  int Rn = (instr & 0x0000F000) >> 12;

  if (bits[21])
    strcat(instructionPtr, "MLA");
  else
    strcat(instructionPtr, "MUL");
  PrintCCode(instr, instructionPtr);
  if(bits[20])
    strcat(instructionPtr, "S");
  sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "\tR%d, R%d, R%d", Rd, Rm, Rs);
  if(bits[21])
    printf(", R%d", Rn);
}

void ProcessLDM(int *bits, unsigned int instr, char *instructionPtr)
{
  char regList[256] = { 0 };
  int listState = 0;
  int Rn = (instr & 0x000F0000) >> 16;
  int i;

  if (bits[20])
    strcat(instructionPtr, "LDM");
  else
    strcat(instructionPtr, "STM");

  PrintCCode(instr, instructionPtr);

  sprintf(instructionPtr + strlen(instructionPtr), "\tR%d", Rn);
  if (bits[21])
    strcat(instructionPtr, "!");
  strcat(instructionPtr, ", ");
  strcat(regList, "{");
  for (i = 0; i<16; i++)
    {
      if (bits[i] && !bits[i+1])
    {
      sprintf(regList + strlen(regList), "R%d, ", i);
      listState = 0;
    }
      else if (bits[i] && bits[i+1] && !listState)
    {
      sprintf(regList + strlen(regList), "R%d-", i);
      listState = 1;
    }
    }
  strcat(regList, "\b\b}");
  strcat(instructionPtr, regList);
  if(bits[22])
    strcat(instructionPtr, "^");
}
```

**elf.h**

```
#ifndef DisARM_elf_h
#define DisARM_elf_h

typedef struct _elfHeader
{
    char magic[4];
    char class;
    char byteorder;
    char hversion;
    char pad[9];

    short filetype;
    short archtype;

    int fversion;
    int entry;
    int phdrpos;
    int shdrpos;
    int flags;

    short hdrsize;
    short phdrent;
    short phdrcnt;
    short shdrent;
    short shdrcnt;
    short strsec;

} ELFHEADER;

typedef struct _elfProgHeader
{
    int type;
    int offset;
    int virtaddr;
    int physaddr;
    int filesize;
    int memsize;
    int flags;
    int align;

} ELFPROGHDR;

#endif
```

Advice on best practices, syntax and any errors you can see is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As a first thought, how portable is this? You use standard types (int, short, unsigned int etc) everywhere, but the sizes of these vary with platform. You might be better using types from stdint.h, such as int32_t, int16_t etc, which guarantee size.

I'll comment more thoroughly later...

.. Later ... in addition the the above:

- You have assumed the constant 4 in various places. Better as a define, as a const int or as a sizeof().
- You also have many embedded constants sprinkled around. These are better #defined and/or  in inline functions.
- Type names are not normally all uppercase (which is used for defines).
- Define functions in reverse order of use to avoid the need for prototypes.  So `main` comes last. Also all functions except main should be static.
- I prefer to see keywords like `if`, `for` etc followed by a space, as in `if (argc < 2)`
- On errors in system and library calls where `errno` is set, prefer `perror` to your own fprintf message. People are used to seeing the system error messages.
- Inconsistent used of `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` and `return 1` (or 2, 3 etc)
- `main` is much too big for my taste - extract some code into suitable functions.
  For example, the reading of the file header and checking its prefix might be a suitable function. Similarly, printing header info might be suitable as a function.
- don't cast the return from `malloc` if this is meant to be C (seems to be).
- system calls should be checked for failure (eg fseek, fread etc).  Note that you'll end up with more calls to `fclose(fp)` and `free(prgHdr)` scattered around if you add failure checks. It is often better to allocate a resource and then pass it into a function that uses it; then free the resource when that function returns, whether on success or failure.
- your `+ 3 & 3` terms should be coded in terms of the types you are using - eg `(... + sizeof(int)-1) & (sizeof(int)-1)`.  This gets messy so an inline function to do the math  would be better.

In `Disassemble`:

- Parameter `armI` should be const
- `startAddress + i*4` is duplicated

In `DecodeInstruction`:

- use `char instruction[100] = "";` instead of `sprintf(...,"\0");`
- you have an combination of printing into `instruction` and printing directly to `stdout` (from PrintASCII)
- your decomposition of the instruction into the `bits` array is really unnecessary and is rather ugly.  Instead of saying `if (bits[27] && bits[26] && bits[25] && bits[24])` etc, it would be better to do:

  ```
  if (isXXX(instr)) {
       processXXX(...);
  } else if (isYYY(instr) {
       processYYY(...);
  } else ...
  ```

  where `isXXX` is defined along the lines of:

  ```
  #define XXX_BITS    0xf000000 
  #define XXX_BITCODE 0xe000000 
  static inline int isXXX(unsigned int instr) 
  {
      return (instr & XXX_BITS) == XXX_BITCODE;
  }
  ```

In `PrintCCode`, the switch is missing a `default` case.

In `PrintASCII`, the array in not needed. Also, printing one char is better done with `putchar`

... I got this far and no further. After this it gets rather messy and difficult to read. It would also be difficult to test and maintain.  I imagine there are cleaner ways of doing this.

Note that `sprintf` and `strcat` are in general frowned upon as they often result in buffer overflows.